# Fix Join table functions or not duplicate values?

Tags: sql, sql-server, navicat

So I have a query in NaviCat, it has a part that looks like this:

```
case
when base.table = 1 then Table1.Name
when base.table = 2 then Table2.Name
when base.table = 3 then Table3.Name
when base.table = 4 then Table4.Name 
end as Name
```

As the Base table has the Identifier Number, but does not contain the Names of the person. It is connected properly and works. However, It is tripling some rows in certain cases.

I can get a response back that looks similar to this

```
Identifier         Amount              Name
12                 1000                Smith, Suzy
12                 1000                Smith, John
12                 1000                Smith, John & Smith, Suzy
```

I would like it to only return the longest entry (as all the Names are either Husband, Wife, or Husband & Wife), as all the amounts are the same and I think it is because I am left joining the Base table to the Table1, Table2, etc. But how can I fix this? Is there a function to only return the longest Name?

I am looking at a few left joins similar to this.

```
Left join server.table1 as Table1 on Base.Identifier = Table1.Identifier AND Base.Date = Table1.Date
```

each table1-table4 has the same join code.

Comment: One part of the code only has `CASE`.  Another part only has `LEFT JOIN`.  How do you think people are supposed to help you?

Comment: why do you need to fetch 3rd row only? And why all three rows are similar names?

Comment: The problem is that sample code can not be provided in an answer based on only this - however, what is for sure, that if a table duplicates rows in the result, then it is not being joined on its primary key (PK) column. You need to either join on PK, or need to find another column to filter on to get always only one match.

Comment: @DávidLaczkó thank you! So this means there is no function that can be used to say "hey these names are all similar, let's take the longest one as the one to put in  the table." ? If not, I'll keep looking to fix the PK or filter on another.

Comment: Indeed it is possible. But please update your request from "I would like it to only return the bottom entry" to "I would like it to only return always the longest ones", if it is what you want to do - the former does not state, we can only guess, that the longest one is always that you want. E.g. I interpreted it as "the latest" entry.

Comment: noted. and changed. I understand the confusion factor of my post.  Thanks again

Comment: @DávidLaczkó, your assertion about using the primary key to join is flatly wrong. Take the standard `header` and `lines` pattern. The `header` PK joins everything together, multiple `lines` are anticipated by the model, and _most_ queries joining the two will return multiple rows, which will be the correct result.

Comment: @EricBrandt But I am talking about when `lines` is joined on its PK or not - of course, in your model it is certainly not, but on its FK, otherwise makes no sense. But not all models are like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can only provide a "raw" `SQL` solution, as I never used `NaviCat`.
Below solution assumes that for every `Identifier` in any of `table1`-`table4`, the `Amount` and the `Date` values are the same.
Your `FROM` should be changed like this:

```
left join (
    select Identifier, Amount, Date, MAX(LEN(Name)) as LongestName
    from server.table1
    group by Identifier, Amount, Date
    UNION ALL
    select Identifier, Amount, Date, MAX(LEN(Name)) as LongestName
    from server.table2
    group by Identifier, Amount, Date
    UNION ALL
    select Identifier, Amount, Date, MAX(LEN(Name)) as LongestName
    from server.table3
    group by Identifier, Amount, Date
    UNION ALL
    select Identifier, Amount, Date, MAX(LEN(Name)) as LongestName
    from server.table4
    group by Identifier, Amount, Date
    ) as tables1to4 on Base.Identifier = tables1to4.Identifier AND Base.Date = tables1to4.Date
```

and your `case` expression becomes only

```
tables1to4.LongestName as Name
```

and the same applies to `Amount`, if it is needed in the end result (no `case` necessary).